# Wrong year in the Last modification time of files inside a directory

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, date-time

My system is Windows 2003 Server + NTFS and in some directories it is storing the Last modification date incorrectly whereas the Creation Time is still fine. The offset is exactly one year in the past: the last modified date is older than the creation date!!!. Did you experience similar problems? What is the explanation and solution for recovering to a normal situation?

I just hope it is not an indication that our disks are getting old (in which case it would be rather unlikely that this phenomenon is visible on all files in a given directory...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely to be down to a date inconsistency between the time on the server and the time on the client pc. You should check both to make sure they're correct.

Comment: No sorry date and time are fine on both computers.

Comment: Sorry just to be clear I mean the date on the client pc that last modified the image.

Comment: After drilling down to a cause, it seems that the path where these files came from originate from a computer which date/time settings are wrong (not under our control). By simulating it I could reproduce the same behavior, so it is indeed the right answer, what I had doubts about at first. Thanks for the tip!